# Finding Duplicates by group in CSV

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, csv

I'm trying to find duplicated records in CSV file. Let me explain what I am trying to do:

[image: Records]

Plate 1 has 2 A800 and 2 B500.

Plate 2 has 2 A800 and 2 B500 it's same as Plate 1. I want to detect this situation.

Plate 3 has 1 A800 and 1 B500.

I tried with 2 nested For Each Loop and stored them inside of 2 dimensional array but if numbers is high this approach is very slow.

What is your advice for this situation?

Comment: For some context, can you show us how you would normally read the raw csv data into memory? That will help is provide an answer that makes more sense to you and fits better with your other code.

Comment: How is your progress? Is this problem solved now? I think the above reply given by Robot can provide you with a solution, have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using GroupBy.  In your GroupBy, be certain use "Key" before every field.  If you use

```
 .GroupBy(Function(F) New With {.Plate = F.Plate,
                                .Part = F.Part}) _
```

the grouping will NOT work.

```
   Private Class cPlate_Part
      Public Plate As Integer
      Public Part As String
      Sub New(Plate As Integer, Part As String)
         Me.Plate = Plate
         Me.Part = Part
      End Sub
   End Class

   Private Plate_Parts() As cPlate_Part =
      New cPlate_Part() {New cPlate_Part(1, "A800"),
                         New cPlate_Part(1, "A800"),
                         New cPlate_Part(1, "B500"),
                         New cPlate_Part(1, "B500"),
                         New cPlate_Part(2, "B500"),
                         New cPlate_Part(1, "A800"),
                         New cPlate_Part(2, "A800"),
                         New cPlate_Part(2, "A800"),
                         New cPlate_Part(3, "A800")}

   Private FindDuplicates()
      Dim GroupedParts = Plate_Parts _
                       .GroupBy(Function(F) New With {Key .Plate = F.Plate,
                                                      Key .Part = F.Part}) _
                       .ToList ' If you don't want it re-evaluated every time you use it

      Dim FindDuplicates = GroupedParts _
                         .Where(Function(F) F.Count > 1) _
                         .Select(Function(F) F(0))

      Dim DistinctParts = GroupedParts _
                        .Select(Function(F) F(0))

      For Each P In DistinctParts
         Debug.Print($"Plate={P.Plate}  Part={P.Part}")
      Next
   End Sub
```

The way GroupBy works is if you have a simple type (such as integer or string), you can simply group by that type.  If it is more complex, create a New With and be sure to use keys as I have shown.  The result is a iEnumerable of iGrouping, which acts mostly like an iEnumerable, but has a "Key" method.

For example

```
for each GroupOfParts in GroupedParts
   dim Key=GroupOfParts.Key
   Dim Group=GroupOfParts.ToList ' Usually Unnecessary
   ' Some code
next
```

EDIT:

Here is an alternate group by using alternate syntax

```
 Dim GroupedParts_AlternateSyntax = From Parts In Plate_Parts
                                         Group By Parts.Part, parts.plate Into Group
```

There is a subtle difference in how it works. You need to use ".Group" method for each item to get the group, or an explicit select

```
Dim GroupedParts_AlternateSyntax = From Parts In Plate_Parts
                                         Group By Parts.Part, parts.plate Into Group
                                         Select Group
```